# Reverse ManyToMany lookup for model with filter

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I am trying to use Django ManyToMany reverse lookup with filtering, values_list and order_by but can't figure it out.

Here is my model (simplified):

```
class Project(Model):
    users = ManyToManyField(User, verbose_name="Users", related_name="project_users", blank=True)
    
    files = ManyToManyField(FileInfo, verbose_name="Files", related_name="project_files",)


class FilInfo(Model):    
    # Name
    name = CharField(_("Name"), max_length=300, blank=False)
    
    # Description
    description = TextField(
        _("Description"),
        max_length=4096,
        validators=[MaxLengthValidator(4096)],
    )    

# User model is a standard Django user model
```

I am trying to get all distinct FileInfo.name for all Projects where self.request.user is a project_user

Here is my obviously wrong attempt as a placeholder: // Doesn't even compile :(

```
FileInfo.objects.values_list('name').filter(Q(pk = project__files__pk) & Q(project__users__pk=self.request.user.id)).distinct().order_by("-" + order_by)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `FileInfo` object you can access Projects through `project_files` related name, and then filter the `users` field for the user.

```
FileInfo.objects.filter(
    project_files__users=self.request.user
).values_list('name').distinct().order_by("-" + order_by)
```